# Reverse last n characters from string using slice notation

Tags: python

Let `s` be a python string and `n` an integer number `n < len(s)`. How can I get the last `n` characters from `s` and reverse them using the slice notation? My attempt is as follows:

```
n = 2
s = '1234'
print(s[-n::-1]) # prints 321, was expecting 43
```

Rationale: `s[::-1]` inverts the string, `s[-n:]` gets the last `n` characters, so I thought that `s[-n::-1]` would return the last `n` characters inverted.

Is it possible to do this on a single slice notation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
n = 2
s = '1234'
print(s[:n-1:-1])
```

EDIT(for any `n`):

```
print(s[:-n-1:-1])
```

Comment: This works with n=2 only by coincidence.  `s[:-n-1:-1]` works for any n.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
print(s[::-1][:n]) #
```